# Finding a specific key in an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some troubles finding the right key in an array:

when I have an array: $haystack

```
$haystack = array(0 => 'apple', 
                  1 => 'apple', 
                  2 => 'pear', 
                  3 => 'apple', 
                  4 => 'banana');
```

and is use the function array_search

```
$key = array_search('apple', $haystack);
```

the function wil set the $key value to '0' ( $key = 0 )

I need to find the key of the fourth item in the array (3) which is also apple...
Does anyone know a function that searches the array from a given index and returns a value?

for example something like:

```
array_search_start($needle, $haystack, $startPosition);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the second parameter to specify value to search keys for.

```
$keys = array_keys($haystack, 'apple');
```

So `$keys` will contain array of found keys corresponding to search value (`apple`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

Now you can get the last one, or the first, etc. If you need the last:

```
$key = end($keys);
```

Comment: This will only give you the last key... OP asked for an offset from a specified index, not necessarily the last one. You should modify to get first key >= `$startPostion`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
function array_search_start($needle, $haystack, $start) {
  for ($i = $start; $i < length($haystack); $i++)
    if ($haystack[$i] == $needle) return $i;
  return FALSE; // You'll need === operator to distinguish between False and 0
}
?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_slice to do this more simply than looping:

```
<?php
$key = array_search($needle, array_slice($haystack, $startPosition,-1,true));
?>
```

This syntax requires PHP>=5.0.2, as we need to preserve the keys (hence the `-1` (no length limit) and `true` which keeps the original keys)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about PHP but, couldn't you just include an offset as the start position?

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

So, in your case you would do

```
$key = array_search('apple', $haystack, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys` to get all keys with values `apple`

```
$keys = array_keys($haystack, 'apple');
```

if you need it to write as a function then you can do:

```
$searchValue = 'apple';
$keys = searchKeys($haystack, $searchValue);
function searchKeys($haystack,$searchValue) {
     $keys = array_keys($haystack, $searchValue);
     return $keys;
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

$array = array("one"=>'paul',"two"=>'lady');
print_r(array_values($array));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$haystack = array(0 => 'apple', 
                  1 => 'apple', 
                  2 => 'pear', 
                  3 => 'apple', 
                  4 => 'banana');
$find = 'apple';
foreach ($haystack as $k=>$v) {
    if($find == $v) {
            echo 'found! key is '.$k.'<br />';
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will be so easy to use**

```
$haystack = array(0 => 'apple', 
                  1 => 'apple', 
                  2 => 'pear', 
                  3 => 'apple', 
                  4 => 'banana');

$keys = array_keys($haystack,'apple');
foreach($keys as $k):
    $searchK[] = $haystack[$k];
endforeach;

print_r($searchK);
```