# PHP - Search key in associative array

Tags: arrays, key, associative-array

I want to find specific array key and return value. here is my code

```
$user_msg = "three";
$array = array(
            'one'=>"1",
            'two'=>"2",
            'three'=>"3"
);
```

Can i use in_array function to find key ? I want check all array with for loop (not foreach). i tested in_array but don't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$keys = array_keys($array) //get all keys from $array
$value = $array[$keys[0]] //$keys[0] == "one"
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated , check that link it will help you :

[Finding a specific key in an php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083197/finding-a-specific-key-in-an-php-array)

and documentation of "array_keys" will help you : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php